# SQL Server CE .sdf merge

Tags: sql-server-ce, compact-framework, sdf

My application is running on Windows CE 6.0, and it uses a SQL Server CE `.sdf` file to store user data. The application is running on an industrial device, which is not connected to internet. The only way to update the software is to plug a USB stick inside.

As expected, the first release 1.0 of the application needs to update to 1.1 now, the database schema as well.

How could I **merge** the .sdf version 1.0 which is on the device with the latest 1.1 database schema that will be available through the File System (USB stick) of the device.

I added a picture below to help understanding my question.

[image]

I am aware about RDA and Merge Replication possibility, but my application is not connecting to a central server through http. Before learning how to use them I would like an expert advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to programatically apply the changes required for the schema to change from 1.0 to 1.1. 
You can do this by using ALTER TABLE/CREATE TABLE statements, combined with inspecting the current schema by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views